# How can I stop ffmpeg from quitting when it reaches the end of a named pipe?

Tags: ffmpeg, fifo

I'm using a program which continuously writes MPEG-TS video data to a file while it's running. I'm expecting it to run continuously for many days.

I want to use ffmpeg to transcode this video data live. So that the .mts file doesn't grow continuously until I run out of hard drive space, I'm trying to get the first program to write to a named pipe and for `ffmpeg` to read from that pipe.

I tried doing `ffmpeg -i /tmp/test.mts -c:v libx264 test.mp4` but it seems that ffmpeg quits once it reaches the end of the pipe, instead of waiting for new data. For example if I start the program, wait 30 seconds and then run ffmpeg, I'll only get ~50 seconds of video out. (30 seconds + the time it takes ffmpeg to catch up)

I have managed to get it working by doing `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 test.mp4 < /tmp/test.mts` but this feels kind of hacky to me, using stdin to do this. Is there a way I can directly provide the named pipe as an input to ffmpeg and have it wait for new data once it reaches the end of the current data?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does it feel hacky to put a standerd input into a standerd input field?

Comment: I don't understand how `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 < fifo.mts` is different in this regard from `ffmpeg -i fifo.mts`; both will receive an EOF and exit here when the (last handle to the) writing end of `fifo.mts` is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply open that fifo for writing (and keep it open) from another place, too. Example:

In a window:

```
mkfifo /tmp/test.mts
exec 7<>/tmp/test.mts
ffmpeg -i /tmp/test.mts out.mp4
```

In another window:

```
cat ... >/tmp/test.mts
cat ... >/tmp/test.mts
```

The idea is that a reader won't receive an EOF from a pipe until all processes which had it open for writing have closed it:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo
$ cat /tmp/fifo &
[1] 26437
$ exec 7>/tmp/fifo
$ echo yes >/tmp/fifo
yes
$ echo yes >/tmp/fifo
yes
$ echo yes >/tmp/fifo
yes
$ exec 7>&-
$
[1]+  Done                    cat /tmp/fifo
```

Without the `exec 7>/tmp/fifo` which keeps an open handle to the writing end of `/tmp/fifo`, the `cat` would've terminated after the first `echo`.

Comment: The weird thing is, the process that's writing to the fifo doesn't end if I do the `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 test.mp4 < /tmp/test.mts` thing. From tests I've done, the process writing to the fifo exits as soon as ffmpeg exits.